# Extract key/value pairs js file

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

Trough `msbuild` target tag i am copy a file (if exist) to a new target and changing his name (it is working properly):

```
<!--///////////////////////////Target CopyOldWebConfigJs//////////////////////////////////////////////-->       

    <Target Name="CopyOldWebConfigJs" Inputs="@(ContentFiltered)" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy" DependsOnTargets="webConfigJsCase">               

        <Exec 
            Command= "copy &quot;D:\p\Deployments\p\\WebPages\web.config.js&quot; &quot;$(AssemblyRoot)\WebPages\web.config.serverCopy.js&quot;"
        />      

    </Target>

    <!-- New target to pre-filter list -->
    <Target Name="webConfigJsCase"
            Inputs="@(FileToPublish)"
            Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy">
        <ItemGroup>
          <ContentFiltered Include="@(FileToPublish)" Condition="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch('%(FileToPublish.Filename)%(FileToPublish.Extension)', 'web.config.js')) AND     Exists('D:\\p\\Deployments\\p\\WebPages\\web.config.js')" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <!--///////////////////////////End Target CopyOldWebConfigJs//////////////////////////////////////////////-->
```

The target file `web.config.serverCopy.js` is a file that have key/value pair content:

```
///////////////////////////////// TEST VERSION //////////////////////////////////////////////
//This is used for general web config settings for .js scripts that _webconfig. from staging to production
//It should not be edited or copied

_webconfig = new Object();

_webconfig.env = "pageq03"; // Needs Replacing

_webconfig.deployment = "p"; // Needs Replacing

_webconfig.relativeWebServicePath = "../WS/"; // Needs Replacing
_webconfig.webServiceFileName = "API.asmx";  // Needs Replacing

_webconfig.errorReportingThreshhold = "High";                                                  // Setting for reporting bugs via email. Set to "Low" to report everything. ["Low", "Normal", "High" or "None"]

_webconfig.customPreviewPhaseDuration = 1000;                              //Setting that controls how long the automatic preview sits and resolves conflicts prior to showing the preview. Higher numbers increase performance while lower numbers enchance user experience.

//_webconfig.NewRelicAppID = {4}; //2805166


//J.A.C.K.A.L. settings (all false by default)
_webconfig.skipBootstrap = false;
_webconfig.skipJqueryUI = false;
_webconfig.skipPOCommon = false;
_webconfig.skipPOCampaignPreviews = false;
_webconfig.skipPOAjaxMonitor = false;
_webconfig.skipIconFonts = false;
_webconfig.skipCookie = false;
_webconfig.skipTouchPunch = false;
_webconfig.skipWebFont = false;
_webconfig.skipJSON = false;
_webconfig.skipKnob = false;
_webconfig.skipGoogleCharts = false;



_webconfig.jqueryuiTheme = "redmond";

//preview scrolling
_webconfig.previewScrollType = "always";                                    //none | onRender | onChange | Always
_webconfig.previewScrollSpeed = 500;                                        //in milliseconds


//Dyanamic Menu
_webconfig.openMenuLinksInSearch = true;

//WIDGET SETTINGS
_webconfig.masterWidgetPath = "widgets/"; //end '/' required
_webconfig.widgetAnimateResize = false;
_webconfig.widgetAnimateSpeed = 100; //ms
_webconfig.widgetDestroyAnimationSpeed = 900;
_webconfig.widgetDebugModeOn = false;
_webconfig.widgetULIdToUse = "widgetSortable";
_webconfig.widgetToolbarAnchor = "#tblNavigationBar";
_webconfig.widgetFavoritesMiniMenuAnchor = ".navBarRight";
_webconfig.widgetScrollToDuration = 700; //in milliseconds
_webconfig.widgetSelectionIndicatorPhaseDuration = .5; //in seconds
_webconfig.widgetSelectionIndicatorNumOfPhases = 4;
_webconfig.allowUseOfWidgetFavorites = true;
_webconfig.POServicesAppName = "p.PO.Services"; // Needs Replacing
```

Now after copying it (backup it), I have 2 missions, i need to read his content and

1. Save the value that `_webconfig.deployment` holds - that value need to replace the path of the `source` path `CopyOldWebConfigJs` target tag `Exec` commands holds(now it hard-coded) - i don't see how it can be done.
2. Every key/value that have the phrase `// Needs Replacing` at the end of it's line, i need to save it's value and insert it's content to other `web.config.js` on the same directory, with the same structure (same key names).

I am kinda new to `MSBUILD` and any help with it will be much appreciated..

Comment: Might be possible using msbuild, though it seems more of a job for some scripting language. So if there's a languag you have more experience with, just use it then invoke it with MsBuild's Exec task?

Comment: I can instead use power-shell, will it be easier?

Comment: I do not know, you should ask that yourself, I don't know how epxerienced you are with PS. If you know how to do it in powershell, in MsBuild you just invoke it like <Exec Command="powershell -noprofile ExtractKeyValuePairs.ps1"/>

Comment: No, i don't have an experience with power-shell, but these are the only options i have for this manner. I will need to search for how to extract key/value pairs from a file.

Comment: You'll have to figure out how to use regular expressions, that's going to be the easiest solution